# Extracting skiptoken to make next request safely

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve all of a user's `ownedObjects`. If the user has more than 999 `ownedObjects`, then the results contain a `nextLink`.

The [documentation here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/paging) states that skiptoken should not be extracted to make a different request.

However, I would like to extract it to make my next request. If the other parts of the original request URL match the corresponding parts of the `nextLink` request URL, would this be safe?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume you want to make an different request to get more result of the user's `owenedObjects`.

Based on my test, we can use the `nextLink` property to make a different request.

As the description of [the official document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/paging), `Do not try to extract the $skiptoken or $skip value and use it in a different request.`

Comment: but why not? What is the problem with it?

Comment: Depending on the API that the query is being performed against, the @odata:nextLink URL value will contain either a $skiptoken or a $skip query parameter. About why do not try extract the `$skiptoken`, we can submit a ticket to get more detail information [at here](https://office365.uservoice.com/).